# GLSL. Change texture coordinates (or texture) for one object in shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vao

For my little 3D editor needs a transform gizmo with a clear and convenient interaction with user. For this reason my gizmo it's not just a polylines, but quads with a textures. Gizmo has 3 quads and a 2 textures for each quad with arrow pictures - for active and inactive states (as an option - a one texture with possible to offset current texture coordinates from one arrow to another arrow) .

Texture arrows:

[image]

I need when a cursor will over the one arrow a corresponding arrow will change a color (change texture or coordinates). 
I managed to change the coordinates by offsetting fs_in.texCoords in fragment shader, but it changes all of my coordinates, this is not what I need.

My arrows is simmilar but I don't want to draw the same VAO 3 times and reinicialize a new VAO with new texture coordinates. 
My VAO just a one array:

```
vertices =
    {   //POSITION FIRST QUAD       //TEXTURE FIRST QUAD
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,         0.3f, 0.3f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,          0.3f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,           0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,          0.0f, 0.3f,                         
        ...
        //POSITION SECOND QUAD      //TEXTURE SECOND QUAD
        ...
        //POSITION THIRD QUAD       //TEXTURE THIRD QUAD
    };
```

I want render gizmo at once in the one VAO, but in this case I don't know how to change texture only for the one quad in shader. Is there a trick or cheat how to implement it in shader?

Comment: Use a texture array and select the z sample depending on some value in the vertex stream (i.e. add a z to your texture uv with the array index for whichever texture you want to select).

Comment: You could load a uniform offset to add to your texture coords depending on which arrow you want to render. A solution along these lines would probably be most efficient